# Error while loading pickle file: - Errno 13 Permission denied: 'data' pkl file

Tags: file, machine-learning, module, model, pickle

[Error in Model Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu7EV.png)

Here, the error is occurring while loading a pickle file. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

use the below codes and it should work.

```
import os
from joblib import load
from joblib import dump
#creating directory
if not os.path.exists("models"):
     os.makedirs("models"
# saving model best estimator
rffinal=model.best_estimator_
dump(rand_forest, 'models/rffinal-clf.joblib')

#loading saved model
random_forest=load('models/rffinal-clf.joblib')
```